# Use a reference with a thick accent?

Tags: references

I previously worked a job in the United States for a company whose workforce included a large number of Indian nationals. I worked at this company for a fairly long time, most of the time under the same manager. I got along great with him, I'm sure he would say positive things about me, the only problem is I believe English is probably his 3rd (maybe 4th) language. It took me a while to get used to his speaking and being able to understand him, and I remember it being difficult to understand him on the phone at first.

Should I not use him as a reference? I have a couple of co-workers I could use as references from this company, but I feel like I was here long enough where it would be much better to have a direct supervisor listed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the references I've been involved with have been written and there hasn't been a need to actually talk to someone.

I would seriously consider using this manager as a reference and assume that the request would be via email, so there shouldn't be any problem.

Don't forget that other people might not have the same difficulty in understanding accents that you might do.

Comment: Just to add: Usually your references will be able to tell you how they prefer to be contact (e.g. by phone or by email) if they have a preference at all. If this manager's preference is to be contacted by email, then specify that.

Comment: Funny-  I've never had a reference check in writing, its always been a call.